# Android Studio not building

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a chunk of Java code that fails to build in Android Studio. It's a pretty simple calculator of someone's mortgage payments. I'm new to this IDE but insofar as I could see it didn't point out any errors I had. So I copy pasted it into VS and other IDEs hoping they'd point something out but not only did they not do that they actually ran it and gave desired results.

```
public class MortgageModel {
    private double p;
    private int n;
    private double r;
    public MortgageModel (String a, String b, String c) {
        p = Double.parseDouble(a);
        n = Integer.parseInt(b) * 12;
        r = (Double.parseDouble(c) / 12) / 100;

    }
    public String computePayment() {
        double base = (1+r);
        double numerator = r*p;
        double denominator = 1 - Math.pow(base, -n);
        double output = numerator / denominator;
        return String.format("$%,.2f", output);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MortgageModel myModel = new MortgageModel("70000", "30", "4.4");
        System.out.println(myModel.computePayment());

        myModel = new MortgageModel("300000", "20", "4.5");
        System.out.println(myModel.computePayment());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android apps do not run this way. Instead of the static main function, you need to have at least one activity declared in the manifest. From the activity, you can call various functions.